# WooCommerce для товаров создает доп. картинки (450x450 и 100x100). Как это отключить?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Задача - импортировать очень много товаров в Wordpress из XML.

Для решения задачи я нашел плагин WP All Import. Он работает отлично. Но проблема в том, что при импорте картинок создаются доп. картинки с размерами: 450x450 и 100x100. Из-за чего на МОЕМ хостинге не хватает места.

На хостинге клиента место будет, но клиент не согласится на сделку, пока не увидит, что я могу импортировать все товары из XML.

Вопрос. Как запретить Wordpress'у создавать доп. картинки? Я понимаю, что это нехорошо - выводить в превьюшки товаров оригинальные картинки, которые вообще могут быть 4К. Но, как я уже сказал, это только для того, чтобы показать клиенту, что я могу импортировать его товары в Wordpress.

P.S.
Изначально Wordpress создавал больше картинок, но я зашел сюда и везде поставил 0:

```
/wp-admin/options-media.php
```

Но это не помогло с размерами 450x450 и 100x100.

Comment: Эти миниатюры создаются темой и/или плагинами. И если они создаются. значит где-то используются, а значит нужны. Если ты не знаешь как от от них избавиться - ты точно не сможешь определить где и когда они используются. А значит - не нужно это и пытаться делать. Куда полезнее научиться нормально оптимизировать графику.

Answer (score 0):

Запретить создание миниатюр для новых изображений можно этим кодом:

```
<?php
function remove_default_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    // Wordpress
    unset( $sizes['thumbnail'] );
    unset( $sizes['medium'] );
    unset( $sizes['medium_large'] );
    unset( $sizes['large'] ); 

    // Woocommerce
    unset( $sizes['shop_thumbnail'] );
    unset( $sizes['shop_catalog'] );
    unset( $sizes['shop_single'] );

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_default_image_sizes' );
?>
```

Если после этих изменений нужно удалить старые миниатюры, то подойдет плагин "Regenerate Thumbnails".